# State change in Vue

Tags: nuxt.js, state

I recently started working with Nuxt and started making an app for an online store. I get product data via API and use it to create product cards.
And also in each card there is a button, when pressed, the amount of supposedly ordered goods constantly increases. I'm trying to display this quantity, but the changed quantity of the product is not displayed in it's card.

Store:

```js
export const state = () => ({
    categories: [],
    mensClothes: [],
    electronics: [],
    womensClothes: [],
    jeweleries: [],
})
```

Code for getting data via API:

```js
async fetch() {
  this.goods = await this.$http.$get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
  for(let i = 0; i < this.goods.length; i++){
    // console.log(this.goods[i].category);
    this.$store.state.data.categories.push(this.goods[i].category)
    switch(this.goods[i].category){
      case "men's clothing":
        this.$store.state.data.mensClothes.push(this.goods[i])
        break;
      case "jewelery":
        this.$store.state.data.jeweleries.push(this.goods[i])
        break;
      case "electronics":
        this.$store.state.data.electronics.push(this.goods[i])
        break;
      default: 
      this.$store.state.data.womensClothes.push(this.goods[i])
    }
  }
  console.log(this.goods);
  this.$store.state.data.categories = new Set(this.$store.state.data.categories)
},
```

Event triggered method:

```js
addToCart(event) {
  let parent = event.target.closest('.good'),
  parentId = parent.getAttribute('id');
  this.$store.state.data.mensClothes[parentId].amount++;
  this.amount = this.$store.state.data.mensClothes[parentId].amount;
  this.id = this.$store.state.data.mensClothes[parentId];
  console.log(this.$store.state.data.mensClothes[parentId].amount);
  console.log(this.$store.state.data.mensClothes[parentId]);
}
```

Code for adding new object properties to the product:

```js
created() {
  console.log(this.$store.state.data.mensClothes);
  this.$store.state.data.mensClothes.forEach(mensCloth => {
    mensCloth.amount = 0
    mensCloth.totalSum = function(){
       return this.price * this.amount
    }
    console.log(mensCloth);
  })
},
```

Code for creating product cards:

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="good in $store.state.data.mensClothes" :id="good.id" class="good">
    <div class="good-img">
      <img :src="good.image" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="good-description">
      <p>{{good.title}}</p>
      <h5>{{good.price}}</h5>
      <div class="good-btns">
        <button class="look-btn">View product</button>
        <button class="order-btn" @click="addToCart">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="amount">{{good.amount}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: What is not working exactly? What do you see in your Vue devtools?

Comment: The product quantity stays at 0 even though I click on the button and increase the quantity

Comment: What do you see in your Vue devtools?

Comment: You can inspect your local state there, your Vuex store, tracks the emitted events etc...a lot of things that could help you understand what is wrong with your app.

Comment: First of all why are changing `States` directly!? you should create `Actions` and `Mutations` to change the `state` also use `getters` to show on your DOM

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that stores trigger change, you should use `useState` or `ref` for that.

Comment: That should probably be a comment.